# Python Panda grouping one column by unique values, creating new column based off the total count of the unique values before grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I've got an Excel spreadsheet that I'm working with. It has 7 columns, and when finished, it should have 8.

The columns are as follows: App ID, App Name, Due Date, Expiry Date, Team, Server Name, Urgency

A new column called App Count should be created based off the count of unique App IDs.
I'll highlight the key columns in a sample chart below:

Here's a sample of what the data looks like (not exact):

Before the script runs:

```
App ID     Team       App Count   The Rest Of The Columns from here
01111    Frontend        2
12411    Marketing       10 
01111    Backend         3
```

After the script runs:

```
App ID     Team                App Count   The Rest Of The Columns from here
01111    Frontend, Backend        5
12411    Marketing                10
```

Please notice how the team 'frontend' and 'backend' got merged to the same row. Also, please notice how the app count was increased by combining the value of the two same app IDs. And lastly, I'd like to have all of the columns (expiry data, server name, etc) included after, but they require no adjusting.

I have used GroupBy, agg and other things but found that they bump into different issues like columns missing, or, the App Count adding up but not merging into one row and still taking up 2 rows.

Any help is appreciated.

This code here combines the teams and groups by app ID but it causes issues when trying to create a new column for the app count:

`data = result.groupby('App ID')['Team'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try groupby to all the columns. And add apply whzre you will count the  app id

Something like this
df.groupby[App ID, App Name, Due Date, Expiry Date, Team, Server Name, Urgency])['App ID']
.nunique()
or
df = df.groupby(by=[App ID, App Name, Due Date, Expiry Date, Team, Server Name, Urgency], as_index=False).agg({'App ID': pd.Series.nunique})